# Does Ruby or Rails have a "in multiples of" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to get a range of numbers but only by 5. Is there method for this? Perhaps something like: `(0..100).by(5)` (I feel like I've seen this done somewhere...)

I know I can do this: `(0..100).select{|x| x if x % 5 == 0}` Can you suggest alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the method [`Numeric#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step). I am sure it is what, you want.

```
0.step(25,5).to_a
# => [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Answer (score 3):

You want [`#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-step) .

`(0..100).step(5)....`